# Many "Temporary failure resolving" and "Failed to fetch" messages when running apt update command

Tags: apt, package-management

When I run the commands `sudo apt update`, or `sudo apt-get update`, the system is displaying a list of errors that I didn't know how to solve

[image: Err: Temporary failure resolving and W: Failed to fetch for various repositories]

Comment: The term "*Temporary failure resolving*" suggests that you have a networking problem, not an update problem.

Comment: Hello. Please do not have pictures of text, always include the text in the body of the question. The error as mentioned in user535733 s comment points to a problem with the DNS service.